# How to change parent text color after child click on ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, kotlin

I already use a onChildClickListener for handle child clicks, but don't know how to change the parent text color:

```
val clickListener = ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener{
       listView: ExpandableListView?, v: View?
       , groupPosition: Int, _: Int, _: Long
       ->
       listView?.collapseGroup(groupPosition)
       true
}
expandable_list_view.setOnChildClickListener(clickListener)
```

Comment: If you want to set a different text color for collapsed and expanded groups: the [ExpandableListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getGroupView(int,%20boolean,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) has a method `getGroupView()` which takes the collapsed/ expanded state as boolean parameter

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but its not what i want. I want to change the color of a group text after click on one of its childs.

Comment: Then I think you need to keep track of the states (colored/ not colored) for all the group positions and use this information in the adapter's getGroupView() implementation. The OnClickListener just needs to call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(), then getGroupView() will be called and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to Create a list of parents that need colors changed and update them in get parent view, just like nosugar said

```
Set<Integer> coloredParents = new HashSet<Integer>();
val clickListener = ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener{
       listView: ExpandableListView?, v: View?
       , groupPosition: Int, _: Int, _: Long
       ->
       listView?.collapseGroup(groupPosition)
       if(coloredParents.contains(groupPosition))
       {
          coloredParents.remove(groupPosition);
       }
       else
       {
           coloredParents.put(groupPosition);
       }


       true
}
expandable_list_view.setOnChildClickListener(clickListener)
```

//then in groupview

```
View getGroupView(int groupPosition)
{
   if(coloredParents.contains(groupPosition))
   {
      //set color here
   }
 }
```